# Web Scraping Justdial using scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to recursively scrape data from justdial.com with name, address and contact number of different vendors. I am using scrapy but my code doesnt seem to work. I think its because of the wrong html attributes from the website. Please look at my code and suggest edits.
I am trying to scrape the link mentioned in my code in the start urls section. My spider closes after execution but the csv file is filled only with commas and two words 'link' 'title'

UPDATED CODE and LOGS:

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from justdial_sample.items import JustdialSampleItem

class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "justdial"
    allowed_domains = ["https://www.justdial.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456"]

    rules = (Rule (SgmlLinkExtractor(allow=("https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/",
    ),restrict_xpaths=('//a[@id="title"]',))
    , callback="parse_items", follow=True),
    )  

    def parse(self, response):

        titles = response.selector.xpath("//p")
        items = []
        for titles in titles:
            item = JustdialSampleItem()
            item ["title"] = titles.xpath("a/text()").extract()
            item ["link"] = titles.xpath("@href").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

LOGS:

```
    /home/karanagrawal/Downloads/justdial_sample/justdial_sample/spiders/test.py:12: ScrapyDeprecationWarning: SgmlLinkExtractor is deprecated and will be removed in future releases. Please use scrapy.linkextractors.LinkExtractor
  ),restrict_xpaths=('//a[@id="title"]',))
2017-06-08 02:44:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.4.0 started (bot: justdial_sample)
2017-06-08 02:44:44 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'justdial_sample.spiders', 'FEED_URI': 'items.csv', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['justdial_sample.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'justdial_sample', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0', 'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv'}
2017-06-08 02:44:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.feedexport.FeedExporter',
 'scrapy.extensions.memusage.MemoryUsage',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2017-06-08 02:44:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2017-06-08 02:44:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2017-06-08 02:44:44 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2017-06-08 02:44:44 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2017-06-08 02:44:44 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2017-06-08 02:44:44 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2017-06-08 02:44:45 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET https://www.justdial.com/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456> (referer: None)
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': [u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t']}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': [u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t']}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': [u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t']}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': [u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t']}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': [u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t']}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': [u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t']}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': [u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t']}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': [u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t']}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': [u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t']}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': [u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t', u'\n\t\t\t']}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': [u'rusers@justdial.com']}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [],
 'title': [u'Privacy', u' Terms', u' Infringement', u'Smartphone', u'Mobile']}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': [u'EDIT']}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Car-Hire/nct-10076456>
{'link': [], 'title': []}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (100 items) in: items.csv
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 737,
 'downloader/request_count': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 44284,
 'downloader/response_count': 2,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 7, 21, 14, 46, 334165),
 'item_scraped_count': 100,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 103,
 'log_count/INFO': 8,
 'memusage/max': 46583808,
 'memusage/startup': 46583808,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 7, 21, 14, 44, 950591)}
2017-06-08 02:44:46 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Paste the logs you see on your command line.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B10eUYMamUyoYUZVM0Q4OUFGVjA/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B10eUYMamUyoeF8zMi0wSXEwNnc/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Can you copy and paste the full text from the command line instead of sharing an image?

Comment: Done. Please check. Thank you.

Comment: Look at the lines the `DEBUG` log. You are being warned about using things that are deprecated. Probably read the fixes mentioned in log. Also from your logs, it looks like you are not fetching any content. It's just tab and spaces. You should fix the xpath selector for extracting link. And finally instead of `yield item` you can probably do `items.append(item) and `return items` in the last line.

Comment: Thank you. I made the changes with the yield item. But I don't get the changes regarding the deprecated libraries. I'm using Python 2.7.13 at the moment and it doesn't warn me of any unexisting libraries that I imported.

Comment: Also, will this recursively scrape the data from the links on the page or just one webpage page?

Comment: The `ScrapyDeprecationWarning` advice on change the path for your python imports. Also update the question with your updated code.

Comment: I updated my code as per your instructions and got rid of the 3 warnings but i could not get rid of the last one even after changing the deprecated warnings. So i kept the last one unchanged. Please suggest edits to get rid of the last warnings.